# How to store user's preferred currency format in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want the users of my international, multilingual Rails app to be able to set their own currency and currency format.

Right now, I am using translation files to achieve this:

```
de:    

  currency:
    format:
      format: "%n %u"
      unit: "€"
      separator: ","
      delimiter: "."
```

However, this is not flexible enough. What e.g. if a user wants to use the euro but wants the `€` symbol to appear *before* the amount?

So what is the best way to store a user's currency formatting preferences and then use it throughout the application?

I figured to store the user's preferences in the database like this:

```
user.preferences.format = "%n %u"
user.preferences.unit = "€"
user.preferences.separator = ","
user.preferences.delimiter = "."
user.preferences.save
```

And then, in the view:

```
number_to_currency(123.50, unit: user.preferences.unit, separator: user.preferences.separator, delimiter: user.preferences.delimiter, format: user.preferences.format)
```

Is this common Rails practice? What might be a better approach?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I know it's none of my business but why you want to do that?

Comment: Because the app will be useless if users can't choose their own currency format.

Comment: But it makes no sense to me. Each currency has it's own format and most people (all people?) use it. It would make sense though if you want to allow user to change the CURRENCY, but that's a different question.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: Yes, sorry, I meant currency and currency format. I updated my original post above.

Comment: So then if you just include default Rails i18n translations they already have currency format for each language. Of course you have to take info account different currencies for same language (German/Swiss, British/US), this is discussed here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module (yellow box)

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made it better to use individual’s preferences/settings instead of app settings.

But there is still a concern in your new arrangement.

What if an user want to change his currency, say from Euro to Canada Dollar? This will be not so easy in your app because his current amount is in Euro. You need to convert this amount into Can Dollar and take currency rate into consideration which adds complexity. And the amount will not be consistent. For example, if he want to change back to Euro after a few days, it's very likely he will meet a new Euro amount.

My suggestions:

1. Use a consistent amount and currency for everything. Say the price is always US$ 19. The user can have his own currency, of course, but it will be converted from the base amount which is US Dollar.
2. Use separate settings for custom currency and save them into db. You've already done that. And there is a very nice gem which could do it efficiently: https://github.com/ledermann/rails-settings